# In Swiftui, how to check the content from a URLsession?

Tags: download, swiftui, urlsession

I am using SwiftUI in Xcode 11, trying to check the content of a `.txt` file from the internet.

The problem is that the `URLSession.shared.downloadTask` takes time to finish. The code to check the content is always performed before the download is finished. Can anyone help me please? Thanks very much.

Sorry, forgot to add some codes.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.myweb.com/myfile.txt”)!
var myweb = “test”
URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, response, error in

    if let localURL = localURL {
        do { try myweb = String(contentsOf: localURL)}
        catch { print (“test”) }
    }
}.resume()

if myweb != “test” { Call some function here}
```

Comment: Please share more code, so that we can help you. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to create **ViewModel** with *Published* property and change it flag on true statement if downloadTask has finished. Use this property inside *View*